# Azure WebJobs and Snapshot Debugger for Azure

Tags: visual-studio-debugging, azure-webjobs

Is there a way to use the Snapshot Debugger against Azure AppService WebJobs?

I know it works with AppService HTTP applications but I would also like to use it with .NET executables running as Azure App Service WebJobs.

Comment: Developer on Snapshot Debugger here. This might work for continuous WebJobs, but not for triggered. The problem is that SnapshotCollector (the NuGet that you add to your application) monitors exceptions while your app is running and doesn't persist its state. If the app exits (e.g. when the triggered job finishes), all state is lost.

Comment: Howard, I just read your suggestion on the Azure Feedback channel. It appears you are talking about live Snapshot Debugging via Visual Studio and not the Application Insights Snapshot Debugger which triggers on exceptions. I'll loop in the appropriate team for that.

Comment: @pharring Yeah, I had meant the Visual Studio feature.  I am, thanks, aware of the documentation / limitation on Snapshot Collector only working for continuous Web Jobs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really has the default supported scope:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-snapshot-debugger

> Snapshot collection is available for:
>
> .NET Framework and ASP.NET applications running .NET Framework 4.5 or
>   later.
>
> .NET Core 2.0 and ASP.NET Core 2.0 applications running on Windows.
>
> The following environments are supported:
>
> Azure App Service.
>
> Azure Cloud Service running OS family 4 or later.
>
> Azure Service Fabric services running on Windows Server 2012 R2 or
>   later.
>
> Azure Virtual Machines running Windows Server 2012 R2 or later.
>
> On-premise virtual or physical machines running Windows Server 2012 R2
>   or later.

So it was not in above list, I suggest you submit a feature request to the product team:

http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio

Comment: Thanks.  I used the UserVoice link to add this suggestion:  https://feedback.azure.com/forums/357324-application-insights/suggestions/33966553-add-snapshotdebugger-support-to-azure-appservice-w